# BizTalk takes twice a XmlDocument saved by a PowerShell script

Tags: xml, powershell, biztalk, xmldocument

I have a PowerShell script which does the following manipulations:

- opens a .xml file
- replaces a specific value
- saves the new file to a folder watched by BizTalk
- copies the original file to a "success" folder

To get the file content as XML, I'm using like this :

`$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFile.FullName)`

And to save the XML to the new file, I'm using :

`$xml.Save($outFileName)`

After the save, I move the original file :

`Move-Item $xmlFile.FullName $successFolder -Force`

As I said, BizTalk is watching the "$out" folder where the "$outFileName" is saved. It appears that BizTalk is getting more files than generated. We are sure of that, since every file get by BizTalk is logged.

The only way is a concurrent access on the output file during the `$xml.Save`. Meaning that the following steps are executed:

1. `$xml.Save` creates the new file and save the content in the $out folder
2. BizTalk takes newly created file and process it
3. Some steps at the end of the execution of `$xml.Save` recreate the file
4. BizTalk takes the "same" file a second time

To avoid this, I'm saving the `$outFileName` to a temp directory before moving the file to the final folder.

My question : is it possible that the `$xml.Save()` method produces two identical files in such scenario?

Comment: You are reading the file in variable `$xml`, but on the `Move-Item` you suddenly use a different (undefined) variable `$xmlFile`. To me that would mean the original file never gets moved away..

Comment: @Theo, the variable $xmlFile is the original file. So the original file is moved to "$successFolder". The variable $xml represents the XmlDocument object of I get from the file $xmlFile.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice that before.. What happens if you move the original file directly after the import? `[xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlFile.FullName -Raw; Move-Item $xmlFile.FullName $successFolder -Force`. (Adding the `-Raw` switch wil speed things up a bit). P.S. are you sure the move is successful? the script doesn't seem to have any error checking on that.

Comment: Is the location you are saving the file to a DFS (Distributed File System) with a DR fail over server?  We've had a duplicate file issue with one of those with BizTalk.